# Method that calculates sum of a column in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with the following structure:

```
+----------+--------+-------+---------------+
|     cash |  game  |item_id|username       |
+-------------------+-------+---------------+
| 0  10.42 |  test1 |   131 |    my_name_1  |
| 1   4.45 |  test2 |   133 |   my_name_2   |
| 2  123.2 | test1  |    23 |    my_name_1  |
+------------------+--------+---------------+
```

I need to write a method that takes this DataFrame as input and returns the sum of money each user has spent per game. The output should look like this:

```
username    game 
my_name_1   test1 133.62
my_name_2   test2 4.45
```

Any input on how I can do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregating [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and parameter `as_index=False` for return `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.groupby(['username','game'], as_index=False)['cash'].sum())
    username   game    cash
0  my_name_1  test1  133.62
1  my_name_2  test2    4.45
```

Or add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df.groupby(['username','game'])['cash'].sum().reset_index())
    username   game    cash
0  my_name_1  test1  133.62
1  my_name_2  test2    4.45
```